# Why does next function not execute?

Tags: javascript

first i want to check if jquery exists or not then move on to next function. But next function `abc()` is not being executed. Maybe somebody knows why!

```
  window.onload = function () {
    if (window.jQuery) {
      localStorage.setItem("key", "abc");
    } else {
      script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js";
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
  };
  function abc() {
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
      alert(e.key);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Did you try calling the method?

Comment: @NikhilGoyal it should be called automatically

Comment: That code never calls `abc`. The event handler will only be registered if `abc` is called. Also note that the previous bit is a bit odd, setting an item in `localStorage` only if jQuery was *already* defined...

Comment: @gergemail9com - By what? When? Nothing in the question is going to call it or cause it to be called later.

Comment: It won't call unless you do so. You have just created a function but never called. So, it will never execute. If you really want to execute the function automatically, just put the code out of the method. But, I will recommend calling the function explicitly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder okay true and what would you suggest doing when jquery already exists?

Comment: @NikhilGoyal true

Comment: @gergemail9com - Why is it a question whether it exists or not? You should be in control of the page, and/or specifying the dependencies of your script...?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder i don't want to add it twice, and my site is quite big so a lot of extra pages.

Comment: Looks like very uncommon pattern. You add your jquery and that is it. It depends on your site structure where you adding those links. And you just initializing your abc() function but never calling it.

Comment: @gergemail9com - The site of the site is irrelevant. Either the page knows that jQuery is loaded, or that the script above depends on jQuery. But it's up to you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with that code. It sounds like you want to call `abc` when jQuery has been loaded, and for some reason you're allowing for the possibility it may or may not have been loaded prior to this code running. The issues I see are:

- Setting a value in `localStorage` won't cause the function to be run; in fact, nothing in that code will cause `abc` to be run.
- You're not declaring your `script` variable, which means the code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).
- The `load` event on window happens **really, really late** in the page load process, after all images and other ancillary items are loaded. It's generally best to do your initialization sooner than that, by either using `type="module"` on your `script` element (if you're happy to use modules, which are handy) or by setting the [`defer` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-defer), or by putting the script at the very end of the body, just before the closing `</body>` tag (which is compatible with older browsers).

So here's what I might do instead, if I had to allow for this jQuery loaded/not loaded thing and I wasn't able to use modules (see comments):

```
// Use a wrapper if not using modules, to avoid creating unnecessary globals
(function() {
  // Define your initialization function
  function init() {
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
      alert(e.key);
    });
  }

  // If jQuery is loaded...
  if (window.jQuery) {
    // ...init
    init();
  } else {
    // Otherwise, load it and init when it's loaded
    var script = document.createElement("script");
//  ^^^−−−−−−−−− prevents the horror of implicit globals
    script.onload = init; // <=== Calls `init` when the script successfully loads
    script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js";
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
})();
```